# How to deploy files in JAR?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, intellij-idea

I have some method which read some data from the file (actually, it is the bus time).

```
public void readData(String number) throws IOException{
    InputStream fis;
    BufferedReader br;
    String line;
    fis = new FileInputStream("n" + number);
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(new Time(line));
    }
    br.close();
}
```

And I have my files into project with needed info.
But! (I am writing in Intellij IDEA, but deploying in Eclipse)
When I deploy project, my program doesn't see the files.
What should I do?
 
Is thinking about
`fis = RaspFrame.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("n" + number);`
Right?

Comment: well what happens when you try it? :) If you think you have an idea, give it a go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Is thinking about:*

```
    fis = RaspFrame.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("n" + number);
```

> *correct?"*

Yes.  That is (roughly speaking) the way to open a stream to a resource held in a JAR file on your classpath.

(Your existing code is actually reading the files from the file system.  It is presumably working from within your IDE because copies of the files are held in the IDE project directory, and the IDE is making the project directory is the "current directory" when you run the program.)